# show the date and time and path of uploaded files

Tags: javascript

I am doing work in Javascript and I have to show  file location and date and time of this files which are going to upload. But date and time process is not working on Firefox, it is only working in chrome. So what can I do for this to get the date, time and files path?

Comment: Very hard to understand what you are having problems with - please add your current code or even better a http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: What have you done? Show the code.

Comment: please see this link:-  http://pastebin.com/Y0eQDs3k

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is cross-browser way of doing that purely via JavaScript.